# Attempting to create a meeting scheduler in google calendar that populates data from google form submissions

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, google-calendar-api, google-forms

I have followed a YouTube tutorial that converts data from Google Forms (via Google Sheets) and creates a meeting in a Google Calendar using the following script:

```
function eventCalendar() {
  var events = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRangeByName("Meetings").getValues();

  events.forEach(function(e){
    CalendarApp.getCalendarById("********").createEvent(
      "Meeting Request for " + e[2] + " submitted by " + e[1],
      new Date(e[3]),
      new Date(e[4]),
      e[5]
    );
  })
  }
```

The Google Sheet data is as follows:

Column 0 - Form Timestamp

Column 1 - Email Address

Column 2 - Meeting Name

Column 3 - Meeting Start Date/Time (MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM:SS)

Column 4 - Meeting Start Date/Time (MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM:SS)

Column 5 - Meeting Location

I have associated a trigger to this so it only runs when a new Form is submitted which works but I am now finding that it runs the script on the entire data set each time which is my issue.

I am not very experienced with this but is there a way that I can alter this script to only run on the new submissions that come through via the Google Form?

Comment: Location is supposed to be in the options object as name/value pair not stand alone `{location:e[5]}`

Comment: Why not use the data in the form submit trigger event object then you wont need to access the spreadsheet

Comment: @Cooper thank you for your response! I have changed the location as per your comment and that now works :) Yeah, you are right that this is a very basic script and there will need to be some sort of validation to deny conflicting events. Is there a way to include that within the framework that I have at the moment?

Comment: Hi, Dan. Please don't ask new questions in the comments. It limits the replies to only those who have read the specific comment and it also stretches the friendship on the one post=one question rule. Regarding checking for conflicting events, there are many existing questions (and answers)  on StackOverflow and it's not unreasonable to ask that you do some research before asking a new question on that subject.